# Include files from master branch when Jekyll docs are saved in gh-pages

Tags: git, jekyll

I am having problems with Jekyll on GitHub pages. Jekyll sits in the `/gh-pages` branch of the repo. The `gh-pages` also has my `_config.yml`, `/_posts/` etc.

I want Jekyll to read and render some files in the master branch.

How can I do this? Please help!

Comment: Non è possibile. One branch cannot share leaves.

Comment: As said by David, it's not possible. What you can do is merging both branches, or adding your files to gh-pages or creating another repo for those files and link them to your site via http url.